# Gmail 2 factor authentication and Apple Mail

Tags: email, passwords, gmail, apple-mail

Using Gmail's 2FA security, Apple Mail 7.3 occasionally decides that my application-specific password is invalid and forces me to generate a new one. This happens pretty reliably every few days. Generating a new password works for a while, but eventually it says that the login information is invalid. This doesn't happen on any of my mobile devices.

What might be causing Google's 2FA app-specific passwords to become invalid? Any ideas?

Comment: No file cleaners are installed on my mac. I have several other email accounts working with the Apple Mail client, none of which have this problem and none of which use 2FA.

Comment: Do you have another mail app connecting to this account?  Can you "reliably" access this account from a web browser for a few days?

Comment: Both my iPhone and iPad are linked with the account using application specific passwords and I have had no issues with them. The web interface is also completely functional.

Comment: I also have issues in Mail 8.2. It seems to accept the application password for IMAP, but then fails when I try to also add it to the SMTP. Apparently this is all fixed in OS X 10.10.3, but it's enough of an annoyance for now that I may have to go back to using Airmail for Mac.